# Python: How I get the html radio box checked?

Tags: python, html

I'm not familiar with Python and

**I want to search if the radio box is checked.**

here is my HTML code.

```
<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="1" checked>
<input type="radio" name="radio2" value="2"> 
<input type="radio" name="radio3" value="3" checked>
```

I try this code but it doesn't work

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('url', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('User', 'Password'))

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
print soup.find(attrs={'name':'radio1'}).attrs['checked']
print soup.find(attrs={'name':'radio2'}).attrs['checked']
print soup.find(attrs={'name':'radio3'}).attrs['checked']
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435600/determine-which-radiobutton-has-been-selected : check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `has_attr`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

div_test = """
<input type="radio" name="radio1" value="1" checked/>
<input type="radio" name="radio2" value="2"/>
<input type="radio" name="radio3" value="3" checked/>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(div_test,'html.parser')
print soup.find('input',attrs={'name':'radio1'}).has_attr('checked')
print soup.find('input',attrs={'name':'radio2'}).has_attr('checked')
print soup.find('input',attrs={'name':'radio3'}).has_attr('checked')
```

Output:

```
True
False
True
```