# How to check if Radiobutton is selected in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
v = IntVar()
r = Radiobutton(lf,value=1,variable = v)
r1 = Radiobutton(lf,value = 2,variable = v)
```

How to check if Radiobutton is selected? Like if r is selected do something if r1 is selected do something else

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is a stackoverflow discussion on it already and you will find your answers there : here is the link [Click here to see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27435600/determine-which-radiobutton-has-been-selected)

Comment: link-only answers are discouraged on stackoverflow.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer

Comment: this one had already been answered so i added the link :)